# iMac (27-inch, Late 2013) running OS X 10.11.4 restarts during partitioning and doesn't complete Windows 10 installation using Boot Camp Assistant

Tags: macos, mac, windows-10, partitioning, boot-camp

... as well as leaves an empty WINDOWS partition.

Help! What can I do? I'm having a hard time finding any solutions anywhere.

Here's some of my System Information:

```
Model Name: iMac
Model Identifier:   iMac14,2
Processor Name: Intel Core i5
Processor Speed:    3.4 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  4
L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
L3 Cache:   6 MB
Memory: 8 GB
Boot ROM Version:   IM142.0118.B13
SMC Version (system):   2.15f7
Serial Number (system): (ask if you need)
Hardware UUID:  (ask if you need)
```

Storage:

```
Available:  354.45 GB (354,449,752,064 bytes)
Capacity:   999.35 GB (999,345,127,424 bytes)
Mount Point:    /
File System:    Journaled HFS+
Writable:   Yes
Ignore Ownership:   No
BSD Name:   disk0s2
Volume UUID:    (ask)
```

Physical Drive:

```
Device Name:    APPLE HDD WD10EZES-40UFAA0
Media Name: APPLE HDD WD10EZES-40UFAA0 Media
Medium Type:    Rotational
Protocol:   SATA
Internal:   Yes
Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
S.M.A.R.T. Status:  Verified
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Are you saying the boot camp utility is failing to partition, or what? You need to provide us with much more detail in order to make any sort of response.